# Replacing one NSMutableDictionary object in NSMutableArray, replaces all objects

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I am fairly knew to iOS development and I think I jumped into the deep end too fast.

I am trying to replace a `NSMutableDictionary` inside an `NSMutableArray` of dictionaries by using `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:` but when I reload my tableView, all the objects in the array have been replaced by the one I am trying to replace,not just the specific index.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath
  {
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

     if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     }


     if ((self.editing && indexPath.row == [detailsArray count])) {

         cell.textLabel.text = @"Add Detail";

         return cell;
     }

     [cell.textLabel setText:[[detailsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"]];
     [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[[detailsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"desc"]];

     return cell;

}

-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated{

    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if (!editing) {

        [dictionaryList setValue:name.text forKey:@"name"];
        [dictionaryList setValue:description.text forKey:@"desc"];

        [detailsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:IndexHelper.row withObject:dictionaryList];

    }

     [self.tableView reloadData];


 }

// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
   return YES;
}
```

// Override to support editing the table view.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
       // Delete the row from the data source
       if ([detailsArray count] > 0) {

           [detailsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

           [tableView beginUpdates];
           [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
           [tableView endUpdates];
       }
    }
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
       // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view

       [dictionaryList setValue:@"Title" forKey:@"name"];
       [dictionaryList setValue:@"Details" forKey:@"desc"];

       [detailsArray addObject:dictionaryList];

       [[self tableView] endUpdates];
       [[self tableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
       [[self tableView] endUpdates];

     }

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


IndexHelper = indexPath;

UIAlertView *passwordAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"\n\n\n\n"
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Άκυρο" otherButtonTitles:@"Αποθήκευση", nil];

UIImageView *passwordImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"passwordfield" ofType:@"png"]]];

passwordImage.frame = CGRectMake(11,20,262,33);
[passwordAlert addSubview:passwordImage];

name = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16,25,252,21)];
name.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
name.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
name.secureTextEntry = NO;
name.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
name.delegate = self;
name.placeholder = @"Title";
[name becomeFirstResponder];
[passwordAlert addSubview:name];


UIImageView *passwordImage2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"passwordfield" ofType:@"png"]]];

passwordImage2.frame = CGRectMake(11,65,262,33);
[passwordAlert addSubview:passwordImage2];

description = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16,70,252,21)];
description.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
description.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
description.secureTextEntry = NO;
description.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
description.delegate = self;
description.placeholder = @"Details";
[description becomeFirstResponder];
[passwordAlert addSubview:description];


[passwordAlert show];


}
```

---**This is where I am replacing the dictionary in the array**---

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];


    if (buttonIndex==1) {

        if ([name.text isEqualToString:@""] && [description.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
            return;
        }

        [dictionaryList setValue:name.text forKey:@"name"];
        [dictionaryList setValue:description.text forKey:@"desc"];

        [detailsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:dictionaryList];

    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    NSLog(@"%@",detailsArray);

}
```

Comment: I can't see your code where you are showing `UIAlertView`, can you update ?

Comment: I edited the code. I don't know why I forgot to put that part in XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are adding same dictionary at all the indexes to it takes a common reference you have to check and make multiple instances for the dictionary for each index.
It may help you

Comment: If I understood correctly, instead of having a dictionary as a property, declare a new dictionary every time I need it. Right?

Comment: That it! I had to declare a new dictionary every time I replaced the object in the array! You just saved me from another good 5 hours of frustration!

Comment: Yes dear Exactly you have to manage it but creating it a new dictionary evry time then it will not take a common reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in the first of the code below

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    //NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]; //REMOVE THIS LINE

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = IndexHelper; //USE THIS LINE

    if (buttonIndex==1) {

        if ([name.text isEqualToString:@""] && [description.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
            return;
        }

        [dictionaryList setValue:name.text forKey:@"name"];
        [dictionaryList setValue:description.text forKey:@"desc"];

        [detailsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:dictionaryList];

    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    NSLog(@"%@",detailsArray);

}
```